# Tilde in lstinputlisting

Tags: listings, tilde

I am trying to include an R file in my document. There is a tilde in one of the R commands and when I try to use `\lstinputlisting{file.r}`, I get the awkward tilde which appears as if it were a superscript. How can I replace this tilde with a `\sim` from `amsmath`?

Assume the content of `file.r` is "lm(y~x)".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[formats]{listings}
\lstset{ %
    language=R,                     
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,       
}

\begin{document}
\section{Homework}
%* actual homework questions *%

\section{R Code}
\lstinputlisting{file.r}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)' `literate` to replace all occurrences of `~` with `$\sim$` that has a width of `2` regular characters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=R,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  literate=~{$\sim$}2
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{file.r}
lm(y~x)
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting{file.r}

\end{document}
```